# Restore sum of sinusoids function by its sample

Tags: python, math, fft, trigonometry

We have 1000 random dots (x, y) of a function [image: my_func], also possible range of x, a_n and b_n. Given this sample, programmatically approximate the original 10-length arrays of a_n and b_n variables. How?

Comment: What do you mean by `random dots`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also I don't understand 1000 random dots of a function. If you have a random x value, y is obviously not random anymore if you apply the formula.

Comment: @MBo just function value pairs, taken x is random, and y is function value at x.

Comment: I think it has something to do with finite [Fourier Sine Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSineSeries.html).

Comment: @PéterLeéh probably. In original task, however, y equals not to sum of sines, but cosines and sines, for example y = 1.27 * cos(5.72 * x) + ... + 0.94 * sin(2.43 * x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) can do the job. If the x coordinates are evenly spaced, the signal can be windowed and a DFT can be applied, or the autocorrelation of the signal can be computed by mean of DFT to identify its frequencies.

Let's give `curev_fit()` a try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3):
    # x is an array of x value
    return a1*np.sin(b1*b1*x)+a2*np.sin(b2*b2*x)+a3*np.sin(b3*b3*x)

n=1000
#np.random.seed(1729)
xdata = np.random.uniform(0,10,size=n)
y = func(xdata, 1.,1., 10.,3., -4.,1.7)

y_noise = 0.8 * np.random.normal(size=xdata.size)
ydata = y + y_noise

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=[1.,1.,2.,2.,3.,3.],method='lm')
print 'optimal parameters are ', popt

perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
print 'standard deviation of parameters ',perr

#sorting xdata and ydata
for i in range(xdata.size):
    for j in range(i):
        if xdata[i]<xdata[j]:
             temp=xdata[i]
             xdata[i]=xdata[j]
             xdata[j]=temp
             temp=ydata[i]
             ydata[i]=ydata[j]
             ydata[j]=temp

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',label='fit')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The provided sample displays some tricks:

- As the function is defined, parameter can be contrained to be positive by using their square. `np.sin(b1*b1*x)`. Constrains ba also be directly introduced in `curve_fit()`, but it prevents the use of the [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) method.
- As stated in the documentation of curve_fit(), the error on the identified parameters can be estimated by using the values returned in pcov.
  `perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))`

It is likely that it will not work at once if this method is run on 1000 points in order to fit 2*10 parameters. You may try to reduce the number of sine wave or pour any knowledge you can get into the fitted function.

Comment: Unfortunately, with curve_fit I can't get less than 1.7 MAE (pastebin.com/UPuvttQR). Result without bounds is horrible. Ideal answ would be precise variables, but this is also good enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can resample values into uniform grid (constant x-step), then make usual FFT.

In ideal case you will have got a set of peaks with position of i-th peak corresponding to frequency `b(i)` and magnitude correlating to `a(i)` (sadly, not necessary works well in reality)

Another way - calculate [non-uniform Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform) using sum - it is quite reliable for your sample count 1000 and limited frequency range. Note that you have to calculate resulting F (magnitude correlating to a(k)) for every needed frequency b(k).

```
F(b(k)) = Sum[j=0..N-1](Y[i]*exp(-2*i*Pi*X[j]*b(k)))
```

---

Forgot to mention - perhaps some frequencies are too close, and you might need some method of optimization like [Levenberg-Marquardt one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) to separate them.

Comment: many thanks. How can I actually implement this in code (Python or something)? 1000 value pairs are stored in a dict, output should be a[10] and b[10].

Comment: What is known about b values?